# apk not visible error after build from unity for oculus quest 2

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, apk, oculusquest

I tried to build an application for oculus quest2 in unity engine. I completed all the requirements, when try to build the apk at required path, a pop-up appears and completes the build process and pop up closes.
But the apk file not visible at the desired file path. I even tried to find the hidden apps and the thing is apk file is appearing in recent files in the system, but not visible at file path. So I can't upload the apk in meta developer hub, even I tried to drag and drop the file in the developer hub.

I tried to search to solve the error but I couldn't get the solution.

So, can anyone solve my issue.

solve the issue how to find the apk file and is there any steps to take while build the apk.